# Merging two XML files with the help of metadata (date) if conflicts arise

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml, xml.etree

I want to merge two XML files (actually translation memory TMX files) with the caveat that two files can contain two versions of an entry. The file format is something like this:
`file1.tmx`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx11.dtd">
<tmx version="1.1">
  <header creationtool="OmegaT" o-tmf="OmegaT TMX" adminlang="EN-US" datatype="plaintext" creationtoolversion="4.1.5_0_10418" segtype="paragraph" srclang="ZH-CN"/>
  <body>
    <tu>
      <tuv lang="ZH-CN">
        <seg>SourceEntryToBeTranslated1</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv lang="EN-US" changeid="user" changedate="20190119T074530Z">
        <seg>I is John.</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu>
      <tuv lang="ZH-CN">
        <seg>SourceEntryToBeTranslated2</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv lang="EN-US" changeid="user" changedate="20190119T075550Z">
        <seg>Other Entry 2</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

`file2.tmx`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx11.dtd">
<tmx version="1.1">
  <header creationtool="OmegaT" o-tmf="OmegaT TMX" adminlang="EN-US" datatype="plaintext" creationtoolversion="4.1.5_0_10418" segtype="paragraph" srclang="ZH-CN"/>
  <body>
    <tu>
      <tuv lang="ZH-CN">
        <seg>SourceEntryToBeTranslated1</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv lang="EN-US" changeid="user" changedate="20190415T064114Z">
        <seg>I am John.</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu>
      <tuv lang="ZH-CN">
        <seg>SourceEntryToBeTranslated3</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv lang="EN-US" changeid="user" changedate="20190119T074550Z">
        <seg>Other Entry 3</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx11.dtd">
<tmx version="1.1">
  <header creationtool="OmegaT" o-tmf="OmegaT TMX" adminlang="EN-US" datatype="plaintext" creationtoolversion="4.1.5_0_10418" segtype="paragraph" srclang="ZH-CN"/>
  <body>
    <tu>
      <tuv lang="ZH-CN">
        <seg>SourceEntryToBeTranslated</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv lang="EN-US" changeid="user" changedate="20190415T064114Z">
        <seg>I am John.</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu>
      <tuv lang="ZH-CN">
        <seg>SourceEntryToBeTranslated2</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv lang="EN-US" changeid="user" changedate="20190119T075550Z">
        <seg>Other Entry 2</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu>
      <tuv lang="ZH-CN">
        <seg>SourceEntryToBeTranslated3</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv lang="EN-US" changeid="user" changedate="20190119T074550Z">
        <seg>Other Entry 3</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

I can use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to merge the files, but it will then depend on the order I merge the files, giving rise to different versions. Notice that the metadata `changedate` actually includes a date-time stamp.

I'm not sure how to parse the element trees to actually take the 'latest' entry version when merging.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
def run(files):
    first = None
    for filename in files:
        data = ElementTree.parse(filename).getroot()
        if first is None:
            first = data
        else:
            first.extend(data)
    if first is not None:
        print(ElementTree.tostring(first,encoding='UTF-8'))
```

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel. There is a utility called "TMXMerger" mentioned right on the ["OmegaT resources" page](https://omegat.org/resources).

Comment: TMXMerger doesn't merge based on the latest date. I was using it and the output was dependent on what order the files are placed in. Sometimes, the files merged are all in different orders (different entries different datetimes), so TMXMerger doesn't work for my use case.